# Is self-documenting code worth potential performance issues?

Tags: c++, templates, enums, self-documenting-code, enum-class

I created small class that allows me to use enumerators of strongly-typed enums as flags (in combination). I'm using type_traits for underlying type detection so it should be also slightly type safe and mostly processed at compile time. However, i was wondering if it is really worth it.

I can now write something like

```
void Foo(Flags<Mode> Value);
```

and the programmer will see that he can use only enumerators from Mode (e.g. Mode::Read) and also he can't combine any other enums with Mode. Do you think it is better way than

```
void Foo(int Mode);
```

, i'm not sure if people can appreciate it?

Comment: What is the performance cost of doing this?  Measure it, and you can probably answer your own question...

Comment: These should optimize into exactly the same code... This is the beauty of C++; you can make tons of compile-time assumptions (the most fundamental being types) which don't incur any run-time overhead.

Comment: @EricJ., the difference (if any) is probably so low that it would be extremely difficult to profile the difference. You'd be better off inspecting the generated assembly code.  See http://mortoray.com/2012/07/09/pitfalls-of-performance-testing/

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Exactly :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are suggesting is considered best practice.

With a modern optimizing compiler there should be no performance cost.

Comment: As i said, i use it to detect underlying type of enum to achieve maximal flexibility (it's templated).

Comment: Thank you very much! I almost forgot to add a static_assert to check if T is enum.